# Service fails to start when failover kicks in

Tags: cluster, high-availability, windows-cluster

I created a Windows Service which hosts a WCF application looking at/binding to the Clustered MSMQ
The Windows service was first installed on both nodes of the cluster.

I then created a cluster of this through the high availability wizard (selecting Generic service).

The client which is sending data to the clustered MSMQ (external from the cluster but same domain/network) sends to the Clustered MSMQ fine.

One of the nodes in the cluster sees the data through the Windows Service (ive got debugging trace to verify this)

Then, when say NodeA goes down, NodeB *should* kick in but it fails to start the Clustered Windows Service with no explanation at all!

It does this several times and still fails. I have to start the Windows Service manually on this Node through services.msc then it works just fine and the service is up and running and continues to process the messages from the Clustered MSMQ.

something clearly isn't right here. Why does the Clustered service fail to "start" when one of the nodes goes down/appears offline? What am I doing wrong? Wrong setting somewhere?

Thank you.